# Insert a value to a list within a list - python

Tags: python, list

Say I have the following:

```
wholeList = ['a', 'b', ['1', '2', '4'], 'c', 'd']
```

How do I add the value '3' into the numeric list within wholeList, at the point after the value '2' but before the value '4'?

Comment: With Python you can experiment in the shell. I would be surprised if a couple of minutes of experimentation wouldn't be enough for you to discover an answer. What have your experiments led to?

Comment: Note that, if your structures will be sorted, bisection can provide an efficient way to find the appropriate location for insertion.

Answer (score 1):

Index to the correct sublist, then use `list`'s `insert` method.

```
wholeList[2].insert(2, '3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.searchsorted` and `insert` functions within a list comprehension :

```
def custom_insert(arr,val):
     return [list(np.insert(sub,np.searchsorted(sub,val),val)) if all(i.isdigit() for i in sub) else sub for sub in arr]
```

Demo:

```
>>> custom_insert(wholeList,'3')
... ['a', 'b', ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'c', 'd']
```

Another example :

```
>>> wholeList = ['a', 'b', ['1', '2', '4'], 'c',['5','6','7','8'] ,'d']
>>> custom_insert(wholeList,'3')
['a', 'b', ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'c', ['3', '5', '6', '7', '8'], 'd']
```

Here you can loop over your list and for each element check if all of its items are digit then using `numpy.searchsorted` find the index of your `val` argument inside that list and using `numpy.insert` insert the value inside that array at the founded index.

Answer (score 0):

You can append `'3'` in the list using `append` method

```
wholeList[2].append('3')
```

Also if you wish to preserve the order use `insert()`

```
wholeList[2].insert(2, '3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the list within the list supposed to be sorted? If so, then perhaps this can solve the problem. Although I imagine Kasramvd has already answered your question.

```
def append_list(passed_list):
    rtn_list = []
    for item in passed_list:
        if type(item) is list:
            item.append(3)
            rtn_list.append(sorted(item))
        else:
            rtn_list.append(item)
    return rtn_list
```